# How to create stored procedure to calculate beginning stock, stock in, stock out, stock balance in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables:

- `Product` (`Product_Model, Product_Color, Product_Code`)
- `StockIn` (`StockIn_Date, Product_Code, Product_SerialNo`)
- `StockOut` (`StockOut_Date, Product_SerialNo`)

I want to create a stored procedure to generate report with requirement fields below:

- (beginning `stock`, `stock in`, `stock out`, `stock balance`)
- Group by (`Product_Model`, `Product_Color`, `Product_Code`)
- Filter by 2 parameters: `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`

How to create a stored procedure with this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your tables **StockIn** and **StockOut** have a column **Amount**, instead the question is senseless.

So, the ugly and the simple query is:

```
SELECT 
  BeginningStockIn
  IsNull(BeginningStockIn.Amount, 0)-IsNull(BeginningStockOut.Amount, 0) BeginningStock,
  IsNull(PeriodStockIn.Amount, 0) StockIn,
  IsNull(PeriodStockOut.Amount, 0) StockOut,
  IsNull(BeginningStockIn.Amount, 0)-IsNull(BeginningStockOut.Amount, 0)+IsNull(PeriodStockIn.Amount, 0)-IsNull(PeriodStockOut.Amount, 0) StockBalance
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date < @StartDate
) BeginningStockIn ON BeginningStockIn.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockOut
  WHERE StockOut_Date < @StartDate
) BeginningStockOut ON BeginningStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date >= @StartDate AND StockIn_Date < @EndDate
) PeriodStockIn ON PeriodStockIn .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockOut
  WHERE StockOut_Date >= @StartDate AND StockOut_Date < @EndDate
) PeriodStockOut ON PeriodStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
```

And **the answer** - to create the stored procedure you have to use `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

```
CREATE PROC YourProcName
  @StartDate datetime,
  @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  the query

END
```

Comment: thanks Oleg Dok for helpful reply. my scenario is: Product_SerialNo is unique. so I set it as stock, means if they StockIn with 1 Product_SerialNo = it has 1 product in stock. for beginning stock means the stock balance available from the lase (it should be <=@FromDate)

Comment: @Sokea You see the draft - try to adopt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

H,

All credit to Oleg Dok who posted the script above.

Here is the same Data I am working with:

[image]

---

Here is the Code:

```
declare @startdate date = '2012-01-02'
declare @enddate date = '2012-01-31'

SELECT 
  Product.Product_Code,
  Product.Product_Color,
  Product.Product_Model,
  IsNull(BeginningStockIn.Amount, 0)-IsNull(BeginningStockOut.Amount, 0) BeginningStock,
  IsNull(PeriodStockIn.Amount, 0) StockIn,
  IsNull(PeriodStockOut.Amount, 0) StockOut,
  IsNull(BeginningStockIn.Amount, 0)-IsNull(BeginningStockOut.Amount, 0)+IsNull(PeriodStockIn.Amount, 0)-IsNull(PeriodStockOut.Amount, 0) StockBalance
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date < @StartDate
  group by Product_Code
) BeginningStockIn ON BeginningStockIn.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockOut
  WHERE StockOut_Date < @StartDate
    group by Product_Code
) BeginningStockOut ON BeginningStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date >= @StartDate AND StockIn_Date < @EndDate
    group by Product_Code
) PeriodStockIn ON PeriodStockIn .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockOut
  WHERE StockOut_Date >= @StartDate AND StockOut_Date < @EndDate
    group by Product_Code
) PeriodStockOut ON PeriodStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
```

Here is the Output:

```
Product_Code    Product_Color   Product_Model   BeginningStock  StockIn StockOut    StockBalance
1   red 123 5   0   3   2
2   red 456 10  0   3   7
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks Saidur Rahman, but in my scenario, i control stock transaction by Product_SerialNo because it's unique, not Amount. ex. in StockIn i have Product_SerialNo: 12345, if 12345 have no in StockOut means it has 1 in stock.